# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; exception thrown upon running JDBC Post Processor JMeter

Tags: mysql, jmeter, mysql-workbench

I am trying to execute below SQL statements after running the JMeter test plan. But it is always throwing me the exception mentioned in the title of this post.

```
delete from
  request
where
  user_id = 9000;

update
  s_session
set
  total_hours_used = 0
where
  user_id = 9000;
```

I tested these queries in MySQL workbench but they are executing correctly. What could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: You can't use `;` split to 2 SQLs in 2 post processors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One statement - one [PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PostProcessor), you can only run a single SQL [Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html) with JMeter's JDBC Test Element given you use Update statement.

If you need to run 2 queries at once consider coming up with a relevant [stored procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) and invoke it using Callable statement.

More information: [Using JDBC Sampler in JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733769-Using-JDBC-Sampler-in-JMeter)